# Beginner's query: unable to reverse char array in C

Tags: c, arrays

First up: sincere apologies for bringing up such a basic problem requesting attention. I intend to reverse a char array with a user input string by using getchar() & display its reverse using putchar(). [I understand that there may be easier or more elegant ways using printf() & scanf(), but I am keen to find the flaw in my logic below with getchar() & putchar():]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define EOL '\n';

/* Reversing a character array */
int main()
{
int arr_char[10];
int i=0;

/* reading char elements into the array */
printf("Please input the array\n");

arr_char[0]= getchar();
while(arr_char[i]!= EOL && i<=9)
{
    i=i+1;
    arr_char[i]=getchar();

    printf("\ni=%d\n",i);
}
/* display reverse */
while(i>=0)
{
    putchar(arr_char[i]);
    i--;
}
return 0;
}
```

1) I get an error message:

```
  reversing char array\main.c|15|error: expected ')' before ';' token|
  ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

FYI: Line 15 is the

```
while(arr_char[i]!= EOL && i<=9)
```

2) I am also trying to print the counter "i" as to see whether it is being incremented on pressing "Enter" after a character is input and it seems that it does.

3) I have defined the arr_char array as

```
int arr_char[10];
```

with the intention that if someone inputs "-1" as EOF/EOL, then a char array will perhaps not be of much help. Am I right?

Any explanations in helping get my bearings back on'll be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Read about the syntax of preprocessor directives like `#define` and how they work. Hint: They do **not** require a semicolon to terminate the replacement text.

Comment: Thank You! Silly me, overlooked the semicolon. However, how to capture the "-1" or any "Ctl-D" type entry to signify end of field?

Comment: Asking that signals you really should read a good C book. You are loking for `EOF` (not necessarily `-1`!). `ctrl-D` is the Unix-key to close `stdin` actually. Note this is **not** "end of field", but "end of file"! Any field-seperator is application-specific (newline is a typical example for text, e.g.)

Comment: @neo "to capture the "-1" or any "Ctl-D""  --> Something like `printf("Please input the array\n"); int ch; while (i < sizeof arr_char && (ch = getchar()) != EOL && ch != EOF) { arr_char[i++]=ch; } while(i>0) {
putchar(arr_char[--i]); };`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `;` from the end of the `#define`. Macros are done using text substitution, so with the semicolon,

```
while(arr_char[i]!= EOL && i<=9)
```

will become:

```
while(arr_char[i]!= '\n'; && i<=9)
```

which is wrong.

You also have an additional problem in that your code can write to `arr_char[10]`, which is past the end of the array. You need to increase the array size, or change `i<=9` to `i<9`.